# Restart Macbook Pro if "Restart, Sleep, Shut Down" buttons are hidden

Tags: mac, macbook, macbook-pro

In *System Preferences >> Accounts >> Login Options*, we have the option

> Show the Restart, Sleep, and Shut Down buttons.

I was wondering how else will we be able to restart, sleep or shut down the computer if these buttons are disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: **You can't** (sleep, restart, turn off)

The option is there to set the Mac up so other people can't just power it down or restart it. That's why you need administrative privileges to actually change the settings. Btw: The keyboard shortcuts don't work either if the buttons are hidden.

Comment: is there a way to do it from the terminal? like **shutdown -f** or something..

Comment: @Pacerier I think you're mistaking something. The options you describe only remove the buttons from the **Login Screen**, not from the OS X menu.

Comment: +1 @Pacerier Check the location of that setting -- it's clearly about the login window. Also note that buttons and menu items are completely different things.

Comment: @Daniel Beck ok my mistake..

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any way to do that either. It used to be possible if you entered `>restart`, `>sleep`, or `>shutdown` as the username. See http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050603213256255. Now that only works when the "Show the Restart, Sleep, and Shut Down buttons" option is not disabled.